# uninitialized constant Reform::Form::Errors After update bundler and start rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rvm, bundler, reform

After making the last update of my bundler by `bundler update --system` on my macOS Catalina last version update
I got this error

**uninitialized constant Reform :: Form :: Errors**

when I start my rails application server either by `foreman s` or `rails s`

I have tried to see if the dependencies of `reform-rails '~> 0.1.7'` correspond to the update and everything is okay suddenly I do not know what is wrong.
thank you in advance for your help

Comment: For my side i solved this bug by updating reform-rails '~> 0.1.7' to last version reform-rails '~> 0.2.0' 

Hope have help